# "Как повернуть цикл назад?". Tkinter. Python 2.7

Tags: python, изображения, tkinter, label

Имеется кнопка "Вперёд ->", меняющая изображение (*расположенная на "label"*), на следующее. Как сделать кнопку, меняющая изображение на предыдущее?

Код: http://pastebin.com/EAe6n2Ms

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-#
#баг: зависает после последнего изображения#
import sys
sys.path.insert(1,"../MDLS/")

import Tkinter,os,btnnf,textf
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def next_image(event):
    event.widget.quit()

def close_me_now():
    control.quit()

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x800+500+400") #'+%d+%d' % (100,100))#
root.title("Изображения")

control = Tkinter.Tk()
control.geometry("200x300+0+0")
control.title("Навигация")

btn_ni = Tkinter.Button(control,width=10,height=1,text="Вперёд")
btn_ni.bind("<Button-1>",next_image)
btn_ni.place(x=0,y=0)
btn_ni.grid(rowspan=1)

btn_close = Tkinter.Button(control,width=10,height=1,text="Выход",command=close_me_now)
btn_close.place(x=265,y=0)

folder_list = os.listdir('.')
image_forget = None

for f in folder_list:
    try:
        image_load = Image.open(f)
        root.geometry('%dx%d' % (image_load.size[0],image_load.size[1]))
        image_puton = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_load)

        label_image = Tkinter.Label(root, image=image_puton)
        label_image.place(x=0,y=0,width=image_load.size[0],height=image_load.size[1])

        if image_forget is not None:
            image_forget.destroy()
        image_forget = label_image

        root.mainloop()

    except Exception, e:
        pass

control.mainloop()
```

Comment: вот [полный пример кода, как с помощью tkinter можно картинки показывать в Label и вперёд/назад переключать](https://gist.github.com/zed/8b05c3ea0302f0e2c14c)

Answer (score 1):

По-моему нужно просмотреть список в обратную сторону:

```
for f in folder_list[::-1]:
...
```

Comment: И получается, нужно составить две процедуры? А потом к ним обратиться?

Comment: Ну разумеется две. Одну повесить на кнопку Назад, другую на Вперед.